# usermod: cannot lock /etc/passwd, but user is in root group which owns file

Tags: permissions, sudo, root, users

As the title says. Interesting behavior. I just switched over to nologin on root user for security, after adding my user to root and sudo groups. I added a longer sudo timeout as described in the link below. So I should be able to use `usermod` without adding sudo because root owns /etc/passwd and user is part of the root group..no?

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26074/is-there-a-way-to-stop-having-to-write-sudo-for-every-little-thing-in-linux/676564#676564

Also, two more problems I found, likely related.. using guestmount failed from permissions, so I added user to kvm group (owner of the complaining file), but still requires sudo. Also, once mounted, I tried ls to /mnt, but have to use sudo even though /mnt is root:root..?

This isnt a trivial problem, because nologin on root disables most brute force ssh attacks, and yet having to use sudo before things like ll disables any alias.

Comment: The root *group* and the root *user* are not the same entity - you will likely find that /etc/passwd has permissions `-rw-r--r--`  i.e. members of the root group may only read it (same as any others)

Comment: `usermod` is complaining about `/etc/passwd`'s LOCK, not `/etc/passwd`. You shouldn't have to use `sudo` with `ls`. Explore your Mount/Read/Write/Execute problems with `https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld`, a `bash` script to show the permissions, mount options along the path to an object or objects.

Comment: Thanks guys! @steeldriver, ah, that is true. I wonder how many files I would have to change the group perms of to make my user have the power/usability of a redhat wheel user? That is my goal. I did find that sudo -s for some reason still logs into root even with nologin set. So that may be easier to use as a workaround.

Comment: @waltinator, thanks. I tried researching lock files, but it doesnt look like that file has one. Maybe the error is complaining I need to be root even so. It did have a similar '/etc/passwd-'. I wonder if that is something. I know lock files from the standpoint of avoiding collisions, but not for having to be root. I just got to double check, I had to use sudo with guestmount on the VM file, and then yes ls wont work on /mnt w/o sudo. The file is actually owned by the user though, so it must be something within guestmount that needs sudo and causes this. `sudo -s` is working, but not perfect..